# React(Styled Components)Navbar link not working

Tags: reactjs, navbar, styled-components

I am trying to allow the navbar to take you to each part of the website but it isnt working for some reason. It is only a one page website and I have another up & running website with the same Example it takes me right to the section, but on this website it just doesnt seem to work does anyone have a clue? Heres my code from navbar.jsx and a link to the github

https://github.com/Justin7933/chidgo

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
    height: 50px;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Left = styled.div`
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Logo = styled.h1`
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline crimson;
`;

const Menu = styled.nav`
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

const MenuItem = styled.a`
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
`;

const Button = styled.button`
    border:2px solid white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: crimson;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
`; 



const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
        <Wrapper>
            <Left>
            <Logo>chidgo</Logo>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem href="#intro">Home</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem href="feature">Features</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem href="#service">Services</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem href="#price">Pricing</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem href="#contact">Contact</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
                </Left>
        <Button>JOIN TODAY</Button>
        </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Is your other project using client-side routing? How does it handle the hashlinks?

Comment: I am using netlify to run the other app

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I dont master the way that you coded yet, so I might embarrass mysef for lack of knowledge, but, have being said that:

Are you not forgeting to wrapp the proprer places with a < section id="">? Like is show here in the code of your **contact** componet:

```
<Container>
==>>>>  <section id="contact">
  <Wrapper>
    <FormContainer>
      <Title>
        Questions? <br /> Let's Get In Touch
      </Title>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <LeftForm>
          <Input name="from_name" value={toSend.from_name}
          onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Your Name" />
          <Input name="reply_to" value={toSend.reply_to}
          onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Your Email" />
          <Input placeholder="Subject" />
        </LeftForm>
        <RightForm>
          <textarea  name="message" className="TextArea" maxLength="100" value={toSend.message}
          onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Your Message"/>
          <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
        </RightForm>
      </Form>
    </FormContainer>
    <AddressContainer>
      <AddressItem>
        <Icon src={Map} />
        <Text>Plymouth County, Hanson, Massachusetts</Text>
      </AddressItem>
      <AddressItem>
        <Icon src={Phone} />
        <Text>+7812175728</Text>
      </AddressItem>
      <AddressItem>
        <Icon src={Send} />
        <Text>damon.justin@outlook.com</Text>
      </AddressItem>
    </AddressContainer>
  </Wrapper>
 ===>>>  </section>
  </Container>
```

At least, I had looked for thoose "targets" from your navebar and I have not found them in any file.